# Get entire text of document as a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I am developing a firefox extension and ideally would be able to get the whole darn DOM as a string.. forget any data structure. I just want what I see in "view source" in a buffer. I have been checking out javascript references and HTMLDocument etc. with no avail.

Ideally I would be able to write to this buffer as well (seems possible i.e. document.writeLn())  I wish there was a document.read()? Am I just a js noob?

Comment: Be more specific, what exactly are you trying to achieve with this? "Writing into the DOM" isn't nearly as trivial as it sounds (would end up recreating elements, losing event bindings, whatnot), and in most cases, it's just plain wrong. The DOM is a data structure and it should be modified as such, not first serialized and then deserialized again.

Comment: I want to do a search and replace on it

Comment: What kind of content are you looking to replace? Text, tags, attributes?

Comment: i had to type 3 words, because of the filter

Comment: Then you should just recursively loop through the DOM tree looking for the text nodes while replacing their content. Of course, if there's tags between the text it will not be caught. Replacing text that has tags in it is not quite trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want to traverse all the nodes of the DOM? You can do this with document.childNodes, working recursively with each node.

Answer (score 9):

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

How about `document.body.innerHTML`? If you need the head contents as well, you can also try `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML` and append the two.

Comment: `document` doesn't have `innerHTML` property (as least not for Firefox).

Comment: I am not sure if this works in practice elsewhere, but I just tested it in the firefox ext and comes back as null.

Comment: yes, yes - I mistyped. I meant document.body.innerHTML. I have now fixed it and added a suggestion for getting head content as well.

Comment: i tried that, it didn't work in the firefox extension. if you've had success with this please let me know

Comment: @levik: Why not just use `document.documentElement.innerHTML` to grab the `<head>` and `<body>` together.

Comment: maybe for others purposes.. just putting it out there that i've tried that as well. I realize that was not directed at me

Comment: Please note that doing a string replace on this and then putting the HTML back will be both distracting and destructive. When you do this, you'll lose properties and event handlers that were set by script.

Comment: What if the search/replace operation needs to look for the words `span` or `head`? To protect against damage like that, you'd have to parse the HTML anyway. So traverse the DOM instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can load jQuery from a FF extension but -

This came up just the other day as a jQuery question. You can use the jQuery selector $('*').html() to get all the html without the 'html' tags.